# Start one thread at a time with queqe

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am writing a server for some library (python).

I want that while the server is working in his loop it will open 1 thread to do something else.

I am controlling this thread with queue and until there is no return value in the queue i don't want the server to open another thread.

```
try:
    #we have a return in the queqe
    returnValue = threadQueue.get(False)
    startAnotherThread = True
except Empty:
    print "Waiting for return value from thread thread....."
```

if there is some return value in the queue then startAnotherThread  will tell to some if statement to open another thread.

i don't know why it's not working mabye some one have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Init before the server loop:

```
# thread queue
threadQueue = Queue()

# thread numbering
threadNumber = 0

# thread start
threadCanStart = True
```

Inside the server loop:

```
if threadCanStart:
    myThread(threadNumber, threadQueue).start()
    threadNumber += 1
    threadCanStart = False

try:
    #we have a return in the quqe
    returnValue = threadQueue.get(False)
    print "Queue return: ", returnValue
    threadCanStart = True
except Empty:
    print "Waiting for thread....."
```